# Using orientation sensor data for Android game

Tags: android, physics, orientation, sensor-fusion

I'm building a game where a green box floats to different parts of the screen. The user must rotate their phone such that the blue dot intersects the green square. This is different from a standard "roll-a-ball" type game because instead of tilting a 3D surface the ball sits on, the ball always returns to the center point when the phone is held straight. Tilting the phone forward naturally moves the ball up to catch squares that are above its center position, tilting the phone backward moves the ball down to catch squares below it, and same for tilting the phone left and right. The phone has freedom to pitch, roll, and yaw (XYZ). I'm using the Android [SensorEvent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html#values) and the `Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR` to try and accomplish this.

So far, this is our approach.

1. On game start, measure the quaternion returned from the sensor, call it Q1
2. On all timesteps after game start, compute the transform between Q1 and Qi, Qi being any other quaternion.
3. Apply the resulting transformation matrix to the 2D dot on the screen such that it translates appropriately.

I'm stuck on computing a transform between Q1 and an arbitrary Qi. I'm asking here to see how similar games solve this problem, and if our approach is even correct given the types of sensor data coming from Android.

**Figure1**

The bottom two pictures of the phone are side views. The top two pictures are a representation of what's on the screen

[image]